# Cannot create a new Group in alfresco using the REST API (/groups) POST

Tags: rest, post, postman, alfresco, alfresco-webscripts

Greetings to the community! I am trying to create a new user group on alfresco using the REST API following this guide https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/groups/createGroup. I am using Postman to make the REST calls. I have successfully so far managed to create new users using the (/people) (POST) method like shown below:

POST: `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/api/people?alf_ticket=TICKET_<<my_alf_ticket>>` 
and the following JSON in the Body:

```
{
    "userId": "user",
    "password": "pass",
    "userName": "user",
    "firstName": "user",
    "lastName": "user",
    "email": "user@user.com"
   }
```

Unfortunately, when I am similarly trying to create a new group like following

POST: `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/api/groups?alf_ticket=TICKET<<my_alf_ticket>>`

and in the body section

```
{
            "authorityType": "GROUP",
            "shortName": "GROUP1",
            "fullName": "GROUP_GROUP1",
            "displayName": "GROUP_GROUP1"
   }
```

I am facing the following  [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJQpM.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Based on `/alfresco/s/index/package/org/alfresco/repository/groups` there isn't a `POST` webscript at `/api/groups` - what exactly are you trying to do here, add a new root group, or a new subgroup, or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, I am trying to create a new root group and then insert my newly created user inside it.

Comment: @NickAth What Alfresco version are you use?

Comment: @mrgrechkinn I am using alfresco 6.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is old api:

> 1) `POST http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/api/rootgroups/{shortName}` to create group
>
> 2) `POST http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/api/groups/{shortName}/children/{fullAuthorityName}` Adds a group or user to a group.

For new api you should use:

> `POST http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/groups`

CURL

```
curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4=' -d '{
  "id": "TEST_GROUP_ID",
  "displayName": "Group for tests"
}' 'https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/groups'
```

Response

```
{
  "entry": {
    "isRoot": true,
    "displayName": "Group for tests",
    "id": "GROUP_TEST_GROUP_ID"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :). So i assume I should use the new api since I am using alfresco 6.0.0. I POST the following http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/groups with body
{ "displayName": "ALFRESCO_ADMINISTRATORS",
    "zones": [ "APP.DEFAULT","AUTH.ALF"
            ]
  } And come with the following error "errorKey": "groupId is null or empty"," and when i try to include it in my JSON body i get ""errorKey": "Could not read content from HTTP request body: Unrecognized field \"groupId\" (Class org.alfresco.rest.api.model.Group), any ideas??

Comment: @NickAth Try to read api documentation) id - for groupid, displayName and parentIds